# Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController::edit()

Tags: laravel

Im working on editing of an already saved product and i am getting the following error message on my browser

```
  ErrorException in ProductsController.php line 88:
    Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController::edit()
    in ProductsController.php line 88
```

My route controller is as below:

```
Route::get('productsedit', array('as'=> '/productsedit','uses'=>'ProductsController@edit'));
```

The function is as below

```
public function edit($id)
    {
          //find the post in the db and sav it as a variable
        $product = Products:: findOrFail($id);

        //return view and pass in the var previously created 
        return view('/productsedit')->withProducts($product);
    }
```

Where iam i going wrong

Comment: more info on this please

Comment: what is withProducts ? try to use view('/productsedit', compact($product));

Comment: Can you show how you're linking to to this route?

Comment: Sorry @nixonnixus im creating an e -commerce application, i have finished creating adding products part, for now im working on editing individual products and im getting  error message see above

Comment: @GuaHsu `withProducts()` will work in the same way `whereColumnName()` will work with the query builder.

Comment: @Ross Wilson thank you ! i don't know that before ! :)))!!

Comment: @GuaHsu It's alright. A lot of the "magic" that happens with class methods in Laravel is down to the use of `__call` or `__callStatic`. I've found it quite handy to go straight to these methods when looking at classes to see if there are any goodies in it.

Answer (score 2):

In your edit method on your ProductsController you require a parameter (`$id`), but you don't have that value in your route . Which is what this error is saying.

> [Missing argument 1 for
>   App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController::edit()]

Your route:

```
Route::get('productsedit', array('as'=> '/productsedit','uses'=>'ProductsController@edit'));
```

Will have to change to something like this:

```
Route::get('products/{$id}/edit', 'ProductsController@edit');
```

When calling the route in your view it will have to look something like this:

```
'products/{{$product->id}}/edit'
```

Extra:
You might want to take a look at Resource controllers since you are not really following restfull practices when it comes to your routes
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

your should give route id

`Route::get('productsedit/{id}', array('as'=> '/productsedit','uses'=>'ProductsController@edit'));`

and in your function should like this

```
`public function edit($id = null)
{
      //find the post in the db and sav it as a variable
    $product = Products:: findOrFail($id);

    //return view and pass in the var previously created 
    return view('/productsedit')->withProducts($product);
}`
```

hope this work !!!